# Close popup window after inserting data and refreshing datagrid with new data

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using asp.net. I have a main page and one popup window. When I click on the button, the popup window will appear. The popup window contains two text fields and two buttons. One is a submit button () for submitting data and the other is a simple input type button for closing the popup window.

When I click on the cancel button, it closes the popup window. But when I fill out the information in the text box and click on submit, it it will insert the data in the server, but the popup window does not close. I can't see the page properly. The data grid refreshes properly but I cannot perform actions on the page. To do this I have to refresh the page manually.

Please tell me how to close the popup window in asp.net after inserting data into the database.

Here is the code to show and hide the popup window:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../JS/modalpopup.js"></script>
<style>
  *html #dvPopup {
    top: expression(eval(document.documentElement.scrollTop)) !important;
  }
</style>
<table style="background-color: transparent" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td class="heder" valign="middle" height="30" style="padding-left: 10px" colspan="2">
      <img height="13" hspace="5" src="../images/arrow.gif" width="13" align="absMiddle">
      &nbsp;<strong>Destination Management</strong>&nbsp;<br />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Destination Name :
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtDestinationName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtDestinationName">
      </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CssClass="BUTTON" Text="Add"
        Width="70px" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" >
      </asp:Button>&nbsp;
      <input type="button" id="Button1" value="Close"
        onclick="HideModalPopup('dvPopup'); return false;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

quite simple on your server side in the event click handler,

add a script resource of `HideModalPopup('dvPopup');` to your page.

[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178207.aspx) should be of some use to you

Answer (score 0):

The popup window does not close after submit because you are not calling it on submit button

You will have call it after the post is done to server